# How update/remove conda-forge channel from Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to install Orange3 through conda. So I type in Anaconda Prompt

```
conda config --add channels confa-forge
```

After that I try to install Orange3

```
conda install orange3
```

But the Anaconda prompt show this error message

```
CondaHTTPEErroR: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/confa-forge/noarch/repodata.json>
```

So I realize that I write **confa**-forge instead **conda**-forge.

How can I delete the channel confa-forge? Or Can I update the channel to conda-forge?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can use:

```
conda config --show channels
```

This will list your channels

```
conda config --remove channels NOT_WANTED
```

This will remove the channel called NOT_WANTED(Assuming that it is part of your list e.g. your confa-forge)

BTW, I will recommend --append channel insteading of --add adding them

```
conda config --append channels CHANNEL_NAME
```

Why: If you do:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

This will make conda-forge first hit channel. Your anaconda's default channel will get lower priority. Some of your packages will start updating to conda-forge.

Instead, do this:

```
conda config --append channels conda-forge
```

This keeps your default channel high in priority. Packages will be searched on your default before going to conda-forge :)

Comment: Great answer. One thing to point out, based on conda-forge.org recommendations linked below in @rmarin 's answer (https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels) , you may want to add conda-forge as higher priority channel with strict channel_priority and `conda config --add channels conda-forge`.

Answer (score 3):

Also you can also check

http://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels

To see your channels' priorities `$conda config --describe channel_priority`

Answer (score 0):

You could change the .condarc file manually, as a last resort in case none of the other options work for you. Although this isn't recommended as any errors made while editing the file manually might be difficult to fix.